# how can i display a color shade in the bottom half of a video using html css

Tags: html, css, video, background, color-shade

I am having a problem in bringing a color shade at the bottom half of a video which I displayed through html .
I have tried using overlay but it is not working.

Comment: _"I have tried using overlay but it is not working"_ Shows us your code that you've tried if you need help with fixing that code. How can [this example code](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video) be adjusted to show your problem/code when you say _"tried using overlay"_?...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.